# Flex tab's x and y position

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

In a tab navigator, I need to find out the x and y coordinates of each the tabs.
Is there a way to do that?
I am using HBox as Tab in the TabNavigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the positions of the tab buttons:

```
var button:Button = tabNavigator.getTabAt(i);
```

would return the tab at `i`th position. Read its x and y.

```
trace(button.x);
trace(button.y);
```

If you want the positions of tab contents, then use `tabNavigator.getChildAt(i)` to get the container at i and read its x and y.